# Thread in class virtual member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, overriding, virtual-functions

I want to make a threading object, the member function "run" can be overridden.  When I add the word "virtual", it will fail.  Can someone help me - how can i make a threading object. The object can be inherited and the member function can be overridden.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

class thread
{
private:
    static void gangplank(void *ptr)
    {
        ((thread *)ptr)->run();
    }
public:
    void start()
    {
        _beginthread(&this->gangplank,0,(void *)this);
        //this->gangplank((void *)this);
    }
    virtual void run()
    {
        cout<<1;
    }
    ~thread()
    {
        _endthread();
    }
};


class d:public thread
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        cout<<2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    d a;
    a.start();

    return 0;
}
```

The error message:

> "text.exe Has stopped working - Windows is checking for a solution to the problem"

It didn't have compile error.

Comment: When you say "it will run failed" what do you mean? What error do you get?

Comment: the error message is"text.exe Has stopped working - Windows is checking for a solution to the problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove _endthread from destructor.

> MSDN:
>   You can call _endthread or _endthreadex explicitly to terminate a
>   thread; however, _endthread or _endthreadex is called automatically
>   when the thread returns from the routine passed as a parameter to
>   _beginthread or _beginthreadex. Terminating a thread with a call to endthread or _endthreadex helps to ensure proper recovery of resources
>   allocated for the thread.

Ok, I got it now, _endthread in destructor it's not real problem here, you must wait for thread in the main function.

```
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class thread
{
private:
    HANDLE m_handle;
    static void gangplank(void *ptr)
    {
        ((thread *)ptr)->run();
    }
public:
    HANDLE getHandle() const {return m_handle;}
    void start()
    {
        m_handle = (HANDLE)_beginthread(&this->gangplank,0,(void *)this);       
    }
    virtual void run()
    {
        cout<<1;
    }
    ~thread()
    {
        //_endthread();
    }
};


class d:public thread
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        cout<<2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    d a;
    a.start();
    WaitForSingleObject(a.getHandle(), INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, since you just say that it
failed, without saying how, but you don't wait for the thread to
finish in `main`, so you may be destructing the thread object
before the thread starts to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::thread` instead of the native C API. It uses function objects, so you probably won't even need virtual functions. If your compiler doesn't support C++11, then you can use `boost::thread`, which is almost the same (actually, it uses the native API directly).

Here is an example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void run()
{
  std::cout << "run" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(run);
  t.join();
}
```

Or you can also call class members:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
void run()
    {
        std::cout << "run" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::thread t(std::bind(&A::run, &a));
    t.join();
}
```

It is generally advised to use higher-level API if possible instead of creating a wrapper to C library calls yourselves. APIs in the C++ standard (and usually in Boost too) are generally better implemented than an average programmer could do, and it surely saves a lot of time than making a good implementation yourself.